# Pycharm IDE and Jetbrains IntelliJ

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Why does PyCharm IDE launch in IntelliJ Idea's icon in the Windows 7 taskbar?

So, everytime i launch the PyCharm IDE it doesn't open up in the PyCharm icon in the taskbar, it opens up in IntelliJ's icon instead. How do i fix this?

Comment: you have installed both pycharm and idea? its actually not necessary because IntellijIdea has pycharm plug in, so its better to install either pycharm(if you only want to develop in python) or IntellijIdea(the whole package)

Comment: @ruddra, the plugin provides support for python but doesn't give you all the project types that are available in PyCharm nor any of the settings options for things like django or even the interpreter.

Comment: I am not sure about that, because I have been working on Idea for sometime but I didn't notice anything less than pycharm. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Known issue, please vote for [IDEA-126488](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126488)